# IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <@com.borisruzanov.social.dependency.scopes.AuthScope, @javax.inject.Singleton>

Tags: java, android

Just start working with dagger. Have checked and tried all first 10 links from google but nothing help. So the error is

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
        C:\Udacity\app\src\main\java\com\borisruzanov\social\App.java
        Error:(6, 53) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerAppComponent
C:\Udacity\app\src\main\java\com\borisruzanov\social\ui\AuthPage.java
        Error:(11, 53) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerAuthPageComponent
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
        > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <@com.borisruzanov.social.dependency.scopes.AuthScope, @javax.inject.Singleton>
```

Somehow begin error in the application class but before it was working well

```
@Module
public class AppContextModule {

    //Define all needed instances which we are going to use during work of application
    private Context appContext;

    public AppContextModule(Context appContext) {
        this.appContext = appContext;
    }

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    Context provideContext(){
        return appContext;
    }

}
```

All this crashes begins after I tried to make dependency on 3 classes. So below you can see the code of the module
@Module
    public class AuthPageMvpModule {

```
    //Define all needed instances which we are going to use during work of application
    private IAuthPageView iAuthPageView;
    private IAuthPagePresenter iAuthPagePresenter;
    private IAuthPageInteractor iAuthPageInteractor;

    @Nullable
    @AuthPageScope
    @Provides
    IAuthPageView provideIAuthPageView(){
        return iAuthPageView;
    }

    @AuthPageScope
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    IAuthPagePresenter provideIAuthPagePresenter(){
        return  iAuthPagePresenter;
    }

    @AuthPageScope
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    IAuthPageInteractor provideIAuthPageInteractor(){
        return iAuthPageInteractor;
    }

}
```

Please let me know if my question was already solved. That could help me to improve my skill in search for an answer of the question

Comment: I second everything @Tuby said. It seems that you are in need of a short introduction to Dagger. [This](https://youtu.be/Qwk7ESmaCq0) youtube series is a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you difining 2 scopes? `@Singleton` is a Scope aswell as `@AuthPageScope`, dagger can't handle 2 scopes because it doesn't make sense.
Decide whether your dependencies are annotated with `@Singleton` or `@AuthPageScope`.

Secondly, why do you save instances inside your `AuthPageMvpModule`, it's job of dagger to do that, you just have to define methods that provide new instances and dagger will take care of everything based on scope and Components.

Comment: Thank you for help. I have learned a lot of youtube lessons and also read some articles. And now I am just trying to implement this technology in my project. So thank you for your patience and recommendation. They helped me a lot